# Child process inherits a handle from its parent process but fails to write in it

Tags: c, winapi, process

I want to have 2 processes write in the same file. I created a file in the first process (parent) and call the second process (child) . I have made the file inheritable and the second process inherits the handle as a command line argument.

Although the handle is not equal to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, the second process can't do anything with the file. WriteFile() ends with Error 6(the handle is invalid). The same is for LockFile(),Unlockfile().

What is wrong with the code and how can I fix it? I want to make 2 processes work with the same file.

Process 1:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec_attr;
    sec_attr.nLength = sizeof(_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sec_attr.bInheritHandle = true;
    sec_attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;
    //argv[1] - the name of the file I want to create
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1],GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE | 
             FILE_SHARE_READ,&sec_attr,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    STARTUPINFO sinfo;      
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo,sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;

    char cmd[300] = "PATH to process 2";
    CreateProcess(0,cmd,0,0,true,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,0,0,&sinfo,&pinfo);
    char c = '1';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h,&c,1,&w,0); //works fine
    ...
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    HANDLE h = argv[1];
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { 
        //it's okay, h is NOT equal to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE
    }
    char c = '2';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h,&c,1,&w,0);  //error 6
    ...
}
```

P.S. The first process succeeds in writing in the file. By that time the second process has already failed.

Comment: Where do you pass the value of the handle to the child process? Also `HANDLE h = argv[1];` can't be correct, you assign a string _pointer_ to a handle. You should convert the string *value* to a handle.

Comment: if you got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` - this exactly mean that child process wrong get handle value. anyway `HANDLE h = argv[1];` is wrong

Comment: @zett42 HANDLE's definition is like    typedef void* HANDLE. Shouldn't the argv[1] easily convert to void*? If it is wrong,how should I convert it?

Comment: @RbMm there was no ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. The WriteFile() in the second process just didn't write the character in the file and I got the error number by GetLastError() function. What is confusing is that h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,but WriteFile() complains about an invalid handle

Comment: A handle is more like a numeric index into a table. Despite the type it is not an actual pointer. You can do `HANDLE h = (HANDLE) wcstoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);`

Comment: @zett42 I set sec_attr.bInheritHandle true which makes the handle inheritable,and I set the bInheritHandle parameter in CreateProcess() function true,so that the process inherits all inheritable handles

Comment: Yes, but you need to tell the child process the handle value. You already try to read handle from `argv[1]` in child process, so you have to pass handle value via command-line from parent process.

Comment: *WriteFile() ends with Error 6(the handle is invalid).* - you write. *Shouldn't the argv[1] easily convert to void*? - amazing solution :)

Comment: *What is confusing is that h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,but WriteFile() complains about an invalid handle*. try `h = (HANDLE)1` - `h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` - yes ? so this must work with `WriteFile()`

Comment: @zett42 I have tried to do the conversion the way you wrote in your comment but a run-time error aroused,and the child process failed again. When the chid process is 'created',isn't the handle value already given as a command-line argument?

Comment: @RbMm amazing solution? The thing is that I don't have the solution and I seek one. And I wrote void* not void. There is a difference,I guess

Comment: but you need begin little think yourself at begin. try understand some things. really - how string `argv[1]` can be a handle ? until you yourself not understand some very basic things - you not make progress. about `void*` - this is typo, because this editor use `*` as special symbol. but are you understand - why you try doing ? absolute senseless things

Comment: @RbMm Learn some 'basic' grammar before writing about 'senseless' things. I have posted a question and I anticipate an Answer to the question,not some meaningless comments under the post

Comment: this your code `HANDLE h = argv[1];
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)` absolute senseless and say about you not understand very basic things. even after another explain this for you

Comment: @RbMm there is no need for 'another explain this for you'. And maybe you know winapi better than English. But,even if the code I wrote is incorrect and doesn't do what I expected it to,it doesn't mean that the code is 'absolute senseless' and it is a 'very basic thing' that I don't understand. So you'd better stop wasting my time by adding more and more inappropriate comments

Comment: @Grig - you must begin exactly from this line `HANDLE h = argv[1];` - try understand what you doing. can you explain ? and then *//it's okay, h is NOT equal to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE* - so any trash not equal to `-1` is ok ?

Comment: @Grig, a handle can be an address or an index in a table; either way it's an integer value. If you want to pass it on the command line, then you you need to convert the integer to a string. Then the child needs to convert the string back to an integer. For example, if the handle value is 72, then, as a null-terminated UTF-16LE string, `argv[1]` would point to the bytes {'0x37', '0x00', '0x32', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00'}, or `L"\x37\x32"` as a C wide-character string literal. Do you know how to convert a string to an integer and vice versa in C?

Comment: @Grig, `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is -1 cast as a `HANDLE`. This is an error value returned by some functions (e.g. `CreateFile`) to indicate an error. It's actually a legacy from 16-bit Windows. Most of the Windows API instead uses `NULL` to indicate a failure for functions that return a handle. But that's not at all related to getting `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` when a bad handle (non-existent or wrong object type) is used. Actually, if a function expects a Process handle, then `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is valid, since it's the pseudo-handle returned by `GetCurrentProcess()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be creating the child process with an inheritable file handle, but you are not actually telling the child what the value of that handle is!  The child is looking for that value in `argv[1]`, but the code you have shown is not passing any value in that parameter!  Even if there were, you are not retrieving the value correctly anyway.

Command-line parameters are always strings, so `argv[1]` is a pointer to a null-terminated string, not a handle.  You have to **convert the handle pointer to a string representation** when you put it on the command-line, and then you have to **parse that string back to a pointer** when processing the command-line.

Try something more like this:

Process 1:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec_attr = {};
    sec_attr.nLength = sizeof(sec_attr);
    sec_attr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sec_attr.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0;

    //argv[1] - the name of the file I want to create
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, &sec_attr, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // handle the error ...
        return 1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO sinfo;      
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));

    _TCHAR cmd[MAX_PATH + 16] = {};
    _tsprintf(cmd, _T("\"%s\" %p"), _T("PATH to process 2"), h);

    // TODO: consider using STARTUPINFOEX instead so the child inherits
    // ONLY the file handle and not ALL inheritable handles it doesn't
    // care about:
    //
    // Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32
    // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873
    //
    if (!CreateProcess(0, cmd, 0, 0, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        // handle the error ...
        return 1;
    }

    CloseHandle(pinfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pinfo.hProcess);

    char c = '1';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h, &c, 1, &w, 0);
    ...

    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2)
    { 
        // ...
        return 1;
    }

    //argv[1] - string representation of a handle to an open file
    HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    _stscanf(argv[1], _T("%p"), &h);

    char c = '2';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h, &c, 1, &w, 0);
    ...

    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, having two threads, let alone two processes, share a single file handle is NOT a good idea.  A given file handle only has 1 read/write position in it, so sharing that handle is going to risk the threads/processes stepping all over each other, unless you provide some kind of synchronization between them so only one can access the file at a time.

Consider passing the target filename to the child process and let it open its own unique handle to the file, eg:

Process 1:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    { 
        // ...
        return 1;
    }

    //argv[1] - the name of the file I want to create
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // handle the error ...
        return 1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO sinfo;      
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(sinfo));
    sinfo.cb = sizeof(sinfo);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&pinfo, sizeof(pinfo));

    _TCHAR cmd[(MAX_PATH *2) + 10] = {};
    _tsprintf(cmd, _T("\"%s\" \"%s\""), _T("PATH to process 2"), argv[1]);

    if (!CreateProcess(0, cmd, 0, 0, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &sinfo, &pinfo))
    {
        // handle the error ...
        return 1;
    }

    char c = '1';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h, &c, 1, &w, 0);
    ...

    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc < 2)
    { 
        // ...
        return 1;
    }

    //argv[1] - the name of the file I want to open
    HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // handle the error ...
        return 1;
    }

    char c = '2';
    DWORD w;
    WriteFile(h, &c, 1, &w, 0);
    ...

    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, consider having process 1 duplicate the file handle and then have process 2 inherit the duplicate instead of the original.

Comment: What should I actually set cmd to? In your code you don't modify cmd by printing it,the path and the handle,and I don't understand the meaning of printing it,either. Shouldn't just passing cmd to CreateProcess() function be enough?

Comment: @Grig `cmd` is populated by `_tsprintf()`, and then the result is passed to `CreateProcess()`. `_tsprintf()` is the `_TCHAR` version of `sprintf()`, which writes formatted output to a char buffer instead of the console.

Comment: think `"PATH to process 2"` better pass as is to first parameter of `CreateProcess` when in cmd simply string or base64 representation of handle. and of course *file handle only has 1 read/write position* but no problem and need in this case use explicit offset in Read/Write file - so use the same, duplicated, file handle not a problem

Comment: To clarify the comment by RbMm, sharing a single, synchronous File object between processes is possible if both processes always use the `lpOverlapped` parameter to specify a file offset explicitly instead of relying on the File object's file pointer.